# How to multi-thread using codeigniter famework(PHP)?

Tags: php, multithreading, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework. And i am searching for a best practice to multi-thread using MVC framework of codeigniter.

I am thinking of creating a class in which all the functions will be written to run in a different independent thread.

Please suggest me techniques to multi thread using codeigniter's MVC framework.

Comment: what do you mean multi-thread? Did you ever used multi-thread using php?

Comment: No I have not used multi threading in php. But i want to use it now. I want to know how can i run a function in different thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't **do** multi-threading directly with PHP. Every page load is handled by a single thread.

If you want the value of `function foo()` to be passed to `function bar()` but in a multi-threaded kind of way, you could emulate it with a job queue like Resque or RabbitMQ.

But saying you want multi-threaded PHP is like saying you want a motorbike with four wheels.

Comment: This is a pretty dismissive and patronising answer, you need to read the php manual again or google. First off php process control

https://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php

Also a library doing exactly what the guy needed https://github.com/motanelu/php-thread

Answer (score 1):

Here is a php multi thread library to fork a process into a separate thread, which i am using to exactly what you describe in mcodeigniter

https://github.com/motanelu/php-thread

Answer (score 1):

[php-thread](http://github.com/motanelu/php-thread) doesn't provide real threading, it just forks the process and results in multiprocessing.

If you want real threading in php, use [pthreads](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads). But be aware of the pitfalls!

Important note to read

- https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/6437782