# CodeIgniter Export task blocking navigation

Tags: php, multithreading, codeigniter, export-to-csv

I have a CodeIgniter application which, based on a filter applied to a grid, is able to export the resultset as a CSV file by running a query applied to the grid on the database.
However, when the result set is significant in size and requires a lot of filtering and multiple tables, this export task does take quite a while to complete and the worst part of this is that it's blocking navigation/UI actions.

Is there any way with CI that I can run this task on a different thread or process and download once it's ready? Or something link async tasks in C# (my main programming language these days..)

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use Queues eg [Rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html). This will help since you cannot do multithreading directly in PHP. Please check this >> [How to multi-thread using codeigniter famework(PHP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241050/how-to-multi-thread-using-codeigniter-fameworkphp/29241977)

Comment: Yeah, I had been on that thread previously. Looked at pthread but seemed more complicated than wanted. I already have rabbitmq installed so I'll def take a look at that. Thanks.

Comment: Queues will help in Asynchronous processing

Comment: somethings bothering me. So I can't tell RabbitMQ "run this method on this controller and get me the output file when it's done"? From the samples I've seen, seems like it